# Liquid error when trying to embed twitter feed on GitHub Jekyll page using plugin

Tags: twitter, jekyll, liquid, github-pages, gemfile

I am trying to embed my twitter timeline on my Jekyll Blog hosted on Github.

This is the plugin I am trying to install: https://github.com/rob-murray/jekyll-twitter-plugin

These are instructions I am using to install plugins in general: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/

The site above includes the warning:

> Plugins on GitHub Pages
>   GitHub Pages is powered by Jekyll. However, all Pages sites are generated using the --safe option to disable custom plugins for security reasons. Unfortunately, this means your plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to GitHub Pages.
>
> You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, but you’ll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files."

Does this mean what I am trying to do is impossible, without building the site statically, since I am using Github pages? I am lead to believe not, because I encounter an error even when serving the site locally on my laptop.

However, I get the following error when I place the example `{% twitter https://twitter.com/jekyllrb maxwidth=500 limit=5 %}` into my index.md file. When I do `jekyll serve --watch` locally, it gives the error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 7): Unknown tag 'twitter' in index.md
```

I do not know if the error is in my installing of the jekyll-twitter-plugin, or in the way I am using. For reference, to install the plug I did the following:

1. put `jekyll-twitter-plugin` in my _config.yml file under the `gems:` header
2. put `gem 'jekyll-twitter-plugin'` into my Gemfile
3. did `sudo gem install jekyll-twitter-plugin` locally on my own machine.

Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin is not supported by Github Pages, so it won't work there. The only possibility to use it is to build your site locally before pushing your site to Github Pages.

If you want to install it locally anyway, after adding the gem to `Gemfile`, Install the gems specified in that Gemfile:

```
bundle install
```

Then continue using the plugin tags in your posts.

Comment: I did `bundle install` and `Using jekyll-twitter-plugin 2.0.0` was one of the lines of output. I then put `{% twitter https://twitter.com/i/moments/650667182356082688 maxwidth=500 %}` into a markdown file, and still got the error `Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 7): Unknown tag 'twitter' in index.md` after doing `jekyll serve --watch` What else can I try? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Post your `_config.yml`

Comment: I've tested your config file & twitter tag and works fine. Try running it with: `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138767/discussion-between-marcanuy-and-davido-widre).

Comment: Do you have any guidance for how to "build site locally before pushing to Github pages"? Does that mean you don't have Github build the site for you?

Comment: Answer: I found the solution for what to do here: https://gist.github.com/abhisheknaik96/26ce79ac7a307eb836dcf02a52f87cf2